# WHMCS with django 1.9 python?

Tags: python, django, whmcs

I just want to know if it's possible to use WHMCS with Django framework ?

Thank in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is most definitely possible, but your question lacks some clarity... Aside from the fact that everything is possible if you really put your mind to it (except time travel - I tried), you can use some of the libraries that nice people have written for nice people like you. Some examples:
https://github.com/jawr/django-whmcs
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywhmcs/0.0.2

You will definitely run into problems with newer versions of WHMCS and Django since the libraries haven't been updated since the stone age - but you have something to build on. That often counts for more than you can expect.

But TL;DR (answer in the same style as the question): Yes.